# Doctrine 2 ORDER BY the field of a joinTable

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

I have an Entity defined like this:

```
Munkatars:
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
    fields:
        nev:
            type: text
        [...]
    manyToOne:
        vezeto:
            targetEntity: Munkatars
            inversedBy: alarendeltek
    oneToMany:
        alarendeltek:
            targetEntity: Munkatars
            mappedBy: vezeto
            fetch: EXTRA_LAZY
```

Is there a way to create a query that orders these `Munkatars` objects by their `vezeto`'s `nev` field?

I've tried ORDER BY m.vezeto.nev, but that gave me an error, and the documentation didn't give much information on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must use join like this example:

```
createQuery("SELECT m.nev 
             FROM  Entity\Munkatars as m 
             LEFT JOIN m.vezeto as v
             ORDER BY v.nev");
```